# Is it possible to resolve the `StatusCode` of the `ObjectResult` base of the run-time derived class T value?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, generics, asp.net-core-webapi

Some context:

I'm unit testing a simple `MyController`, for each of the test I'm asserting that the http response object is a specific type of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ObjectResult` base class or any of its derived classes like `BadRequestObjectResult` or `OkObjectResult`.

```
MyController : BaseController
{
    public void IActionResult> Get(...)
    {
        try
        {
            if (...) retrun BadRequest(...)

            return Ok(...);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(500, ...);
        }
    }
```

For example, at the end of each unit test I'm asserting the actual return type is of `ObjectResult` with `HttpCode` of 500 or for the second unit test's return type is of `BadRequestObjectResult` with `HttpCode` of 400:

```
[Test]
public void ControllerTest_WhenFail_ShouldRetrunInternalServerError()
{
    ...
    IActionResult actual = controller.Get(...);
    //Assert
    AssertHttpCode<ObjectResult>(actual, 500);
}

public void ControllerTest_WhenRequestNotValid_ShouldRetrunBadRequest()
{
    ...
    IActionResult actual = controller.Get(...);
    //Assert
    AssertHttpCode<BadRequestObjectResult>(actual, 400);
}
```

Here is the Assert Function for the type casting and asserting the `StatusCode`:

```
private void AssertHttpCode<T>(IActionResult actual, int httpCode) where T : ObjectResult
{
    Assert.IsNotNull(actual);
    T objectResult = actual as T;
    Assert.AreEqual(objectResult.StatusCode, httpCode);
}
```

My Question:

Instead of sending the `httpCode` as a parameter from each of the unit tests, **I wonder if it is possible to resolve the `StatusCode` of the `ObjectResult` base of the run-time T value?** so the clients of `AssertHttpCode` function, won't need to send the `httpCode` as a parameter, like:

```
public void ControllerTest_WhenRequestNotValid_ShouldRetrunBadRequest()
{
    ...
    IActionResult actual = controller.Get(...);
    //Assert
    AssertHttpCode<BadRequestObjectResult>(actual); //no 400 here, it is obvious!
}

private void AssertHttpCode<T>(IActionResult actual) where T : ObjectResult
{
    Assert.IsNotNull(actual);
    T objectResult = actual as T;
    Assert.AreEqual(objectResult.StatusCode, **resolved_http_Code_from_T**);
}
```

Comment: Might not be related to the question, but if you had a global exception handler and a model validator (both ship with ASP.NET Core), you probably wouldn't need any of this

Comment: As for the question itself, you can check the type of `T`, `BadRequestObjectResult` will always have a 400 result

Comment: Hey @CamiloTerevinto, are you suggesting to hard coded check if the type of `T` is `BadRequestObjectResult` and then to check if it is 400?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I liked your first comment even more! I'll use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to determine which status code a certain ObjectResult-deriving type would assign to its [StatusCode property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.objectresult.statuscode?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ObjectResult_StatusCode), as there is no one-to-one relationship between ObjectResult types and status code.

So one implementation can have multiple code paths assigning different status codes based on some conditions, the other can (only) have a user-provided status code and *some* always return the same (unless overwritten from user code).

And besides that, your tests should be explicit in what output they expect (the usual format also is `Assert(expected, actual)`, so switch those parameters). What if some framework update changes the status code of a certain response type? Your test will accept the status code that the type uses, so your test won't break while your API will be giving different status codes in its response.

Comment: Hey @codecaster, thanks for the answer (+1), can you please review my answer below just to be sure

Answer (score 1):

If the object result types you want to check have a parameterless constructor, you can add that to the constraints and do something like this.

```
private void AssertHttpCode<T>(IActionResult actual) where T : ObjectResult, new()
{
    Assert.IsNotNull(actual);
    T objectResult = actual as T;
    var t = new T();
    Assert.AreEqual(objectResult.StatusCode, t.StatusCode);
}
```

Otherwise, you will have to do some pattern matching to see what type it is.

I believe most of the `ObjectResult` types just need an object passed to create them. You can try this instead.

```
private void AssertHttpCode<T>(IActionResult actual) where T : ObjectResult
{
    Assert.IsNotNull(actual);
    T objectResult = actual as T;
    var t = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new object()) as T;
    Assert.AreEqual(objectResult.StatusCode, t.StatusCode);
}
```

You can create a new class for 500 errors to fix your problem in the comments.

```
public class InternalServerErrorObjectResult : ObjectResult
{
    public InternalServerErrorObjectResult(object value) : base(value)
    {
        StatusCode = 500;
    }
}
```

Comment: This was a nice try (+1), but I'm afraid the `ObjectResult` does not have a parameter-less constructor.

Comment: It only works for `AssertHttpCode<BadRequestObjectResult>(actual);` , When I'm trying to assert against 500 with `AssertHttpCode<ObjectResult>(actual);` it does not work, the activator create the `ObjectResult` class properly but it inits it with empty or null values.

Comment: Worth to mention that the `ObjectResult` is the base class, wheres the other derived ones are getting init properly.

Comment: Correct, the initial status code for a base `ObjectResult` is null, so that's technically what the resolved code is. I'm guessing you are using this type for 500 errors?

Comment: Okay, you could create a new class for 500 errors instead of using the base class. (see code above)

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I've found that the `Type-Pattern` ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch#type-pattern)) is very handy in this case (thanks @CamiloTerevinto for the tip):

```
private void AssertHttpCode<T>(IActionResult actual) where T : ObjectResult
{
    Assert.IsNotNull(actual);
    T actualObjectResult = actual as T;
    switch (actualObjectResult)
    {
        case BadRequestObjectResult x:
            Assert.AreEqual(400, actualObjectResult.StatusCode);
            break;
        case OkObjectResult x:
            Assert.AreEqual(200, actualObjectResult.StatusCode);
            break;
        case UnauthorizedObjectResult x:
            Assert.AreEqual(401, actualObjectResult.StatusCode);
            break;
        case CreatedAtActionResult x:
            Assert.AreEqual(201, actualObjectResult.StatusCode);
            break;                    
        case ObjectResult x:
            Assert.AreEqual(500, actualObjectResult.StatusCode);
            break;
        default:
            throw new NotImplementedException();
    }            
}
```

This is also answers the concern raised by @codecaster's answer:

> What if some framework update changes the status code of a certain
> response type? Your test will accept the status code that the type
> uses, so your test won't break while your API will be giving different
> status codes in its response.

Hard coding the assertion will make the unit-test break in a case of a framework update.

Comment: You could just use `T actual` and lose the type check.

Comment: I'm sorry what do you mean by lose the type check?